# Opening Visual Studio project after downloading from github results in "file does not exist in project directory"

Tags: c#, visual-studio

For my coursework, I need to upload my Visual Studios project to a repo on GitHub.  I saved my project, including the .sln, .cs files, etc inside a local repo which was then pushed to GitHub through GitHub Desktop.

I wanted to do a test download to make sure my instructor won't have a problem opening the project.  However, when I downloaded the repo as a zip file and opened the csproj file, all of the files inside that project had a padlock next to them. When clicked, I get the following message:

"The item program.cs does not exist in the project directory. It may have been renamed, moved or deleted."  None of those are true, so I'm confused on what the issue could be.  Here's a screenshot of what I'm seeing: [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mscNT.png).

Does anyone know why I might be seeing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not yet included in project, turn on hidden file from your project (under Solution Explorer -> the third icon from the right) then add them to your project and try to checkin again.

Comment: Thanks, Thieu, I double checked and they are included. Someone said it's because GitHub automatically makes the files locked after a push, but I'm not sure why or how to disable it.